# C# Select Usercontrol from list

Tags: c#, user-controls

I would like to be able to build a number of usercontrols all inheriting the same interfaces, and then have a dropdown in my program listing the names of these controls and opening the selected control in a panel. Is this possible, and how should I organize these models, and ultimately make the control selected load.

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Edit: I know how to make a usercontrol that inherits an interface already, just now sure if they can be loaded dynamically.

Comment: Please provide us with what you have tried.

Comment: You can always just load and hide all of your user controls in a FlowLayoutPanel and show them when the corresponding ComboBox value is selected.

Comment: Let me give you a little more context: I am building a windows form application that uses split containers to create 4 panels. In one of the panels, I would like to have a user control docked. I plan on making a number of usercontrols on a template so that they are plug-and-play. All of the usercontrols will be in a folder in the project, titled ModelControls. Each control could have a lot of code to build the framework for an algo, so i can't load them all in the backgroud. I would like to be able to have many different versions of the control.

Comment: Ideally i could create a list of keyvaluepairs that have the name as a string and the control location or path as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good solution below. Downside is that I have to create a separate dll for the controls, but it will do.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/939afd00-18fd-4ea5-92f1-ec343876b801/dynamically-load-user-controls-from-a-dll-file-in-c-net?forum=csharpgeneral